# Seperate titles from body in String or how to parse by 2 "\n" ? Kotlin

Tags: arrays, regex, kotlin

I have a text which should be saved in android string.xml resources. For this, I want to save it in a list of Data class.

> Title1
>
> Body1 .....
>
> Title2
>
> Body2......

Titles are surrounded with 2 newLines, I need to split titles from bodies. How to do this? Are there any regex patterns?

UPDATE:

if body contains more than 1 paragraphs:

> Title1
>
> Body1 .....
>
> BodyContinuation
>
> New Paragraph
>
> Title2
>
> Body2......

How to handle this case?

Comment: Are they alternate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may parse it in kotlin itself, it'll do it in O(n) steps similar to regex by consuming the line sequence.

Example:

```kotlin
fun parseTitle(str: String): Sequence<String> = sequence {
    var emptyLines = 2
    str.lineSequence().forEach {
        when {
            emptyLines > 1 -> {
                yield(it)
                emptyLines = 0
            }
            it.isNotEmpty() -> emptyLines = 0
            else -> emptyLines++
        }
    }
}

val test =
    """
    Title1

    Body1 .....


    Title2

    Body2......
    """.trimIndent()

println(parseTitle(test).toList()) // [Title1, Title2]
```

---

#### Edit:

If there are multiple paragraphes which contains any number of line breaks then the only constraint you can put to filter them out is by the size.

```kotlin
/**
 * [str] is the input string, [maxLen] is maximum length until which line
 * should be expected to be a title
 */
fun parseTitle(str: String, maxLen: Int): Sequence<String> =
    str.lineSequence()
        .filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
        .mapNotNull { if(it.length <= maxLen) it else null }
        // .toList()  // to trigger terminal operation and collect the result into list
```

Comment: thanks, one more question: if my body contains more than 1 paragraph, how to handle this case?

Comment: @Nurseyit Tursunkulov would it contain 1 line break or 2? If its similar to gap between title and body (1 empty line) then its all ok already.

Comment: @Animesh_Sahu it can contain 2 line break

Comment: @Nurseyit Tursunkulov Then what will be constraint that makes title a title? Length of line? Wouldn't there be more line break between body and next title element than gap between two paragraphs?

Answer (score 1):

You can `.split("\n\n")` your string to get a list of string, then use `.chunked(2) { ... }` to group resulting list into pair of string, mapping each pair to your data class instance.

Example:

```kotlin
data class Item(val title: String, val body: String)

fun parseItems(input: String): List<Item> =
    input.splitToSequence("\n\n")
        .chunked(2) { (title, body) -> Item(title, body) }
        .toList()

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val testData = """
        Title1

        Body1 .....

        Title2

        Body2......
    """.trimIndent()
    println(parseItems(testData))
}
```

It outputs the following:

```
[Item(title=Title1, body=Body1 .....), Item(title=Title2, body=Body2......)]
```

You can play with it here: https://pl.kotl.in/8ix38By7m